# Pandas: how to extract letters (alpha) from string cell value

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am working on a csv file that contains a lot of location data (addresses) and I want to acquire the street name information without the house number.

A sample of the data:

```
pd.DataFrame({'OWNERADDR': ['6612 HOLLY RD', '7618 DRESHER RD', '9062 STEINSVILLE '],
             'STREETADDR': ['7713 DRESHER RD', '7606 DRESHER RD', '9072 STEINSVILLE RD']})
```

[image: Pre]

What I want is:

[image]

Both columns are of str type. But I just want to get rid of the numeric part.

I think there must be a concise way to do it with regular expression. But my lack of knowledge of RE has prevented me from doing so.

Thanks.

Comment: `df.replace('(\d)', '', regex=True)`

Comment: @Erfan Thanks! Does this only replace the leading numbers or all the numbers?